# IIS6 gives a 404 for filenames with spaces

Tags: iis-6

IIS6 is refusing to host files with a space in the name.  The browser requests the file as:  http://mysite.com/files/this%20is%20a%20file.wmv, which is fine.  But IIS just returns a 404 for it.  Replacing spaces with dashes works fine.  This is a new development setup, and the previous IIS6 server hosted the files just fine, so I must be missing a setting somewhere to enable this.

Just to be explicit, the MIME types for the file are set up fine, as evidenced as when I remove the spaces and uses dashes instead.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess - is URLScan or something similar configured on the server and blocking the %20 -> space mapping or resulting URL?

You could test the % mapping question by getting a working url e. g. once with dashes as you said, then replace a character such as %61 for "a".

Comment: I do not believe URLScan is installed.  I can't find it under the %windir%/system32/inetsrv folder, nor under Add Remove Programs.